# Restore SQL Server database by using osql -q

Tags: sql, sql-server, osql

I'm trying to restore a multiple disk/media back up using the below command when I use 1 or 2 disks its fine. In this case I am using 23. It fails with an error query is too long. Could not find any good solution .please help .

```
osql -Q \"restore database dbname from disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak0', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak1', 
disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak10', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak11', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak12', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak13', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak14', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak15', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak16', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak17', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak18', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak19', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak2', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak20', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak21', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak22', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak3', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak4', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak5', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak6', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak7', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak8', disk = 'C:\temp\y.bak9' with move '123_Data' to 'C:\temp\dummy1.mdf', move '123_log' to 'C:\temp\dummy.ldf'\" -S -E"
```

Comment: Can you put the query in a file and use `-i <input filename>` instead of `-Q <query>`?

Comment: Invalid usage of parameter -i ..should I use a .sql file ?

Comment: Here's the [osql documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806(v=sql.105).aspx).  (There's a link at the top to change to the appropriate SQL Server version.)  Note that the command line parameters are case-sensitive.

Comment: The problem its not identifying the fiole correctly ..I used // to distinguish it but still it considers for e.g. if the path is "c://temp//temp.txt" it assumes as "c:temp temp.txt" .I even used a variable name

Comment: osql is not finding the file with the `-i` parameter?  SQL Server can't find the backup file(s) referenced in your script?  Or something else?

Comment: "osql -i out.txt" - msg:  Cannot open input file - out.txt

Comment: You may need a fully qualified path for the file name.  For example: `osql -i "C:\Some Folder\Your DB Restore Script.sql"`

Comment: I did use full path but it omits all // and says can not find file .I think I m doing something very silly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57120/discussion-between-dmason-and-arunachalam).